Effect Composer doesn't work along with Views in React Three Fiber
I am running into a problem with React Three Fiber which I can't find a solution for.
I have one Canvas that I want to add multiple Views for splitting multiple scenes into a single Canvas and without need of having multiple canvases for not hurting performance.
the problem is that I have a sun element which needs EffectComposes, Bloom... For glowing, but I can't make it work along with Views, only without it.
here is the code of the Canvas component:
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import React from 'react';
import { BaseballTest } from './BaseballTest';
import { Environment, Sky, View, Preload } from '@react-three/drei';
import { BaseballField } from './BaseballAnimations/BaseballField';
import EffectsComponent from './components/EffectsComponent/EffectsComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='relative h-full w-full'>
      <div className='w-full h-screen bg-red-700'></div>

      <View className='absolute w-full h-screen z-[999]'>
        <mesh position={[500, 100, 2000]}>
          <sphereGeometry args={[200, 200, 200]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial
            color={'#f0dc2b'}
            emissive={'#e4d125'}
            emissiveIntensity={4}
          />
        </mesh>

        <Sky />

        <Environment
          files='./sky.jpg'
          background
          backgroundIntensity={1}
          environmentIntensity={2}
        />

        <ambientLight />
        <BaseballTest />
        <BaseballField />
      </View>

      <Canvas
        flat
        eventSource={document.getElementById('root')}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '100vh',
          position: 'fixed',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
        }}
        camera={{
          fov: 40,
          position: [-1.385, 13.642, -107.34],
          rotation: [3.006, -0.013, -3.123],
        }}
        dpr={window.devicePixelRatio}
        shadows={true}
      >
        <EffectsComponent />
        <View.Port />
        <Preload all />
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


and here is the EffectComposer component:
import React from 'react';
import {
  ToneMapping,
  Bloom,
  EffectComposer,
  Vignette,
} from '@react-three/postprocessing';
import { ToneMappingMode, VignetteEffect } from 'postprocessing';
import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { damp } from 'maath/easing';

const EffectsComponent = () => {
  const vignetteRef = React.useRef<null | typeof VignetteEffect>(null);

  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    if (vignetteRef.current) {
      damp(vignetteRef.current, 'darkness', 0, 6, delta);
    }
  });

  return (
    <EffectComposer>
      <Bloom
        mipmapBlur
        luminanceSmoothing={0.1}
        luminanceThreshold={1.1}
        intensity={3}
      />
      <Vignette eskil={false} offset={0.1} darkness={1.1} ref={vignetteRef} />
      <ToneMapping mode={ToneMappingMode.NEUTRAL} />
    </EffectComposer>
  );
};

export default EffectsComponent;

I've tried changing places of the EffectsComponent, like putting it below Preload, and also putting it outside of Canvas but inside Views, and nothing seem to work out.
